# Prism(2) Silverlight Reference data

Tags: silverlight, prism

I need to make sure certain essential data are loaded before a module is loaded and shown on screen. considering the async nature of data loading in silverlight, I was wondering if there is a pattern I should follow to load my data (like an event on the module or the bootstrap to hook into, or a method to override)...

Answer (score 1):

you can set module InitializationMode to OnDemand and once you have your data call moduleManager.LoadModule("YourModuleName"); as described [here](http://mokosh.co.uk/post/tag/prism/).

Comment: This way I have to make every single module "load on demand" because all of them rely on ref data...

Answer (score 0):

There's another alternative as well.  If you know you're going to need the module, and the data is statically stored inside another module, you can establish dependencies:

```
ModuleCatalog m = new ModuleCatalog();
...
m.AddModule(typeof(PersonModule.PersonModule), "ModuleA");
```

In this scenario, your module in question would establish a dependency on whatever module has the data, and this would ensure that the data is loaded before-hand.

Comment: I will still have the same problem. how do I ensure that the module with ref data is loaded after the ref data?
ref data loading is async, so there is no guaranty by the time the "module" is loaded, the "data" is loaded too.